# Kinesis Streams support in Siddhi

Tags: siddhi

We are currently evaluating Siddhi and we haven't seen any documentation for Kinesis integration support.

We would like to know whether there are any plans for for Kinesis Streams support.

Comment: Can you bit elaborate about the scenario you are solving by integrating into Kinesis? Because both are doing streaming analytics.
Currently only way to integrate i would see is Siddhi to publish to  firehouse to Kinesis streams

Comment: Fromt the Kinesis stack, we are making use of Streams and Firehose. We need to see whether Siddhi can receive events from Kinesis Streams directly, the same way it can do through Kafka.